# Android Parse Query Returns Not Results

Tags: android, parsing

I am running the following code where I have declared ArrayList 'userHolder'.  There are also two values in the parse server 'User' class with values in the list array (FgiA..., Swu...).   When this code runs I get no results although the values are on the User table in the objectId column.  I am not sure what is wrong since I would expect to get results.

```
    userHolder.add("FgiAXHQCOB");
    userHolder.add("SwuT8v7pIQ");
    Log.i("test", Integer.toString(userHolder.size()));
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("User");  //Query table
    query.whereContainsAll("objectId",userHolder);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null){
                Log.i("Find All", "Retrieved: " + list.size() + " objects in list!");
                if (list.size()>0){
                    for (ParseObject object : list){
                        Log.i("wtf", object.getString("username"));
                    }
                }
                Log.i("Find All", "Success!");
            }
            else {
                Log.i("Find All", "Failed!");
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: is it failing or returning empty list?

Comment: It is running but I am not getting results.  The following line "Log.i("Find All", "Retrieved: " + list.size() + " objects in list!");"   is printing "I/Find All: Retrieved: 0 objects in list!"

Answer (score 0):

`containsAll` is supposed to be used to compare two arrays and requires that the key is an array. In your case, it's a singular value (`objectId`). Try `containedIn` instead.

Comment: I changed the line of code to "query.whereContainedIn("objectId",userHolder);" and I am still getting 0 objects when I would expect to get 2.

Comment: @M.Phillip can you try `whereEqualTo` with a single value?

Comment: I am still not getting a result.  I changed the line to "query.whereEqualTo("objectId","FgiAXHQCOB");"

Comment: Ah.... I figured it out.  I was reading a ParseObject but I believe I needed to be reading using a ParseUser in addition to muratgu's comment to use "whereContainedIn".  Thanks!